# jQuery mobile overwite tabindex attribute

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, tabindex

I am using Phonegap with cordova and jquery mobile. I have one issue regarding tabindex attribute. This is my html code

```
<select id="priority_value" tabindex="6" name="select-choice-b" data-native-menu="false">
   <option value="2">High</option>
   <option value="1">Medium</option>
   <option value="0">Low</option>
</select>
```

When I check it my browser it will take `tabindex="-1"`.

Comment: in your title, do you mean _Override_ or _Overwrite_?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#pageid').live('on',function(event){
   if(event.handled !== true)
   {
      $("#priority_value").attr("tabindex", '1');
      /* OR You can use also */
      var tabindex = 1;
      $('input,select').each(function() {
          if (this.type != "hidden") {
            var $input = $(this);
            $input.attr("tabindex", tabindex);
            tabindex++;
         }
     });
      event.handled = true;
   }
    return false;
 });
```